# Can I combine separate month and year column for this query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently am trying to track the number of messages sent by month as well as the volume's percent change in comparison to one year prior.

---

Here is my current query:

```
Select
    a.mo,
    a.ye,
    a.Messages,
    ((a.Messages - b.Messages) / b.Messages) as "% Change"
from(
        select
            MONTH(post_date) as mo,
            count(*) as "Messages",
            YEAR(post_date) as ye
        from
            pm_messages
        WHERE
            post_date > "2018-01-01 00:00:00"
        group by
            year(post_date),
            month(post_date)
    ) a
    left join (
        select
            MONTH(post_date) as mo,
            YEAR(post_date) as ye,
            count(*) as "Messages"
        from
            pm_messages
        group by
            year(post_date),
            month(post_date)
    ) b on a.mo = b.mo
    and a.ye -1 = b.ye
```

---

This works great, however, it places month and year in separate columns, which has been messing up the graphs I am working with. However, when I try to pull month and year into one columns as I've done in other queries from the same table, i.e. using:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`post_date`,'%M %Y')
```

---

My query does not work.

Does anyone know how I can combine my current query to still calculate the return from a year prior but have month and date come up as one column, as opposed to (Month | Year | Messages | % Change)

Thanks!!
[image]

[image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I'd recommend to publish some sample data (as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO, 5-10 rows enough) and desired result for this data (with explanations). It seems that final query would be more simple than current one.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  I have updated the post to show the database as well as the current outcome. I am trying to have it where the final outcome is exactly what is shown now, except the month and year are combined in one column i.e. 1 2018, or even January 2018 if possible. Thanks!

Comment: @Akina I have updated the post to show the database as well as the current outcome. I am trying to have it where the final outcome is exactly what is shown now, except the month and year are combined in one column i.e. 1 2018, or even January 2018 if possible. Thanks!

Comment: I have asked about CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts. How do you think, are your photos useful for your data reproducing? can I copypaste the structure and data from them?

Comment: @Akina I am new to sql and unsure exactly what you meant. Tried to provide the photos for context.

Comment: Irrelevant to the main question but don't you need to multiply by 100 to get percent?

Comment: yes but even right now in just decimal point its still fine

Answer (score 0):

you can use `extract` instead of separate year() and month() functions :

```
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from post_date)
```

of course you have to group by this instead of year, month . for example :

```
select
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from post_date) yearmonth,
    count(*) as "Messages"
from
    pm_messages
group by
    EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH from post_date)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! only thing is, would this be compatible with taking the "-1" to get the year's prior data?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data for every month, you can use `lag()`:

```
select year(post_date) as ye, month(post_date) as mo,
       count(*) as Messages,
       lag(count(*)) over (partition by month(post_date) order by year(post_date)) as prev_year            
from pm_messages
where post_date >= '2018-01-01'
group by year(post_date), month(post_date)
```